# Зависимая валидация или валидация двух полей

Tags: javascript, валидация, jquery-validation

Использую валидатор

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Имею два поля месяца и года в виде `<select><option></option></select>`
Как правильно написать правило валидации чтобы проверяло текущую дату и сравнивало с введенной например: сегодня 06.18 (месяц.год) и если человек выберет 05.18 не проходит валидацию если 07.18 то проходит.

Comment: Определите ответ и закройте вопрос если вам помогли.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let onMyDateCmpChange = (element) => {
  let value = element.target.value;
  validateMyDateCmp(value);
}

let validateMyDateCmp = (value) => {
  if (!isDateGreaterThanToday(value)) {
    alert("Invalid date");
  }
}

let isDateGreaterThanToday = (date) => {
  let todayDate = new Date(),
    targetDate = new Date(date);

  todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  targetDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  return targetDate > todayDate;
}

let myDateCmp = document.getElementById("my-date-cmp");
myDateCmp.addEventListener("change", onMyDateCmpChange);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
 <select id="my-date-cmp">
  <option value="06.01.2018">06.18</option>
  <option value="05.01.2018">05.18</option>
  <option value="07.01.2018">07.18</option>
 </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

По правильному будет добавление метода к Jquery Validation для своих нужд. Проходит валидацию если выберет сегодняшний день недели по часам что на локалке настроены. Собственно при такой затее надо время в option value и text подтягивать тоже, рендомно вставлять в какой-то option каждый раз. Ну реализация такова, для сравнения времени и.т.д лучше прикрутить Moment.js чтоб велосипеды не изобретать.

```js
var MyDate = new Date();
var MyDateString;
MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getDate());
MyDateString = ('0' + MyDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.'
             + ('0' + (MyDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '.'
             + MyDate.getFullYear();
console.log(MyDateString); // Current Time 
$.validator.addMethod( // Add JQ Validation Method
"dateToday",
function (value, element, requiredValue) {
    return value === MyDateString;
},
"Выберите правильную дату."
);

$('#testform').validate({ // On validation on #t1.
rules: {
  t1: {
    dateToday : 'on'
   }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<form id="testform">
  <div>
    <select id="t1" name="t1">
      <option value="" name="task">Выберите сегодняшнюю дату</option>
      <option value="07.06.2018" name="task">07.06.2018</option>
      <option value="12.12.2016" name="task">12.12.2016</option>
      <option value="02.10.2017" name="task">02.10.2017</option>
    </select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```